# JQuery Mobile responsive table not working for dynamically built table, even after refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make a table where users can choose which columns to show/hide. JQuery (which I'm already using in my site) offers this via their JQuery Mobile "responsive table" widget, specifically the "column toggle" variant.

I can get this to work perfectly if I put the table in the page, so I know the files are importing and my code is correct. The problem is that this table is the result of an Ajax call, so is built inside the $.post() function and placed on the page once built. This part, too, works fine for displaying the table. However, when the table shows, it's not responsive. At least, it lacks the all-important "columns..." link. In $.post(), I construct the table like this, then append to it:
`resultsTable = $("<table id='resultsTable' data-role='table' data-mode='columntoggle' data-column-btn-text='Show/Hide Columns...' class='ui-responsive'></table>");`

I'm thinking the problem is that Jquery Mobile can't hook into the table's creation to modify it, or for some other reason doesn't know it exists. I therefore tried refreshing it just before the end of $.post:
`$("#resultsTable").table("refresh");`

This has no effect. I've tried moving it around, calling the 'refresh' method in different ways, and looking to see if others have had this problem. No results so far. I know the solution must be simple, but I can't find it. I can find plenty about dynamically generating tables, and plenty about responsive tables, but nothing about using them together. I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be best to add example code, what you've tried so far. Also, unsure why you have tagged this for `jquery-ui`.

Comment: have you tried `resultsTable = "<table id='resultsTable' data-role='table' data-mode='columntoggle' data-column-btn-text='Show/Hide Columns...' class='ui-responsive'></table>";`

Comment: Cesar, I was using strings originally, yes, but that made no difference. Doing it this way lets me append to the parts of the table, and makes the code much clearer and easier to maintain. Plus, I thought switching to the $("") way might give JQuery something to hook into. @Twisty, what code would you like? Everything else is just constructing the table, which looks right on the screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After appending the table to the container DOM element, call **[enhanceWithin()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/)** on the container:

```
$("#tableCont").empty().append(resultsTable).enhanceWithin();
```

## **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/tkd1w5te/)**

Click the button in the demo to create a table.

Comment: Ah ha, that did it! I had to remove the call to resultsTable.table() before it worked, but once I did that my link appeared and my columns could be hidden. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I would advise assigning the `.table()` before appending it to the HTML.

In your `$.post()` Success function, it may look like:

```
var resultsTable = $("<table>", {
    'id':'resultsTable',
    'data-role':'table',
    'data-mode':'columntoggle',
    'data-column-btn-text':'Show/Hide Columns...',
    'class':'ui-responsive'
});
resultsTable.table();
resultsTable.appendTo("#results");
```

In this way, the element is set to be responsive before being added.

Also, `refresh` is not a method or event of `.table()`: https://api.jquerymobile.com/table/

I think you may try `.table('rebuild')` instead.